# Webpack / Aws recently stopped deploying, errors in webpack.js

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Has anyone encountered this?  I cannot even run webpack,  I get an error in webpack.js on line 186.   This just started happening to my configuration on AWS

```html
lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:186
  outputOptions.children = options.map(o => o.stats);
                                         ^^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
     at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
     at startup (node.js:129:16)
     at node.js:814:3
```

My Node version is node --version ---- v0.12.10

```html
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "~3.1.1",
    "blueimp-md5": "^2.1.0",
    "chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin": "0.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "~0.8.5",
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-babel": "^6.0.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-webpack": "^1.0.11",
    "install": "^0.6.1",
    "lodash": "^4.11.2",
    "npm": "^3.8.9",
    "pusher-js": "^3.0.0",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.4.1",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.4.1",
    "react-autosuggest": "^7.0.1",
    "react-burger-menu": "^1.10.9",
    "react-cropper": "^0.10.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.7.3",
    "react-flip-move": "^2.7.1",
    "react-logger": "^1.1.0",
    "react-responsive": "^1.2.5",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-tag-input": "^2.2.4",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.3",
    "react-toggle-button": "^2.1.0",
    "react-widgets": "^3.4.5",
    "reflux": "^5.0.3",
    "reflux-core": "^0.4.2",
    "superagent": "~1.6.1",
    "superagent-bluebird-promise": "~3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: currently having the same issue, using webpack taskrunner in VS15.
node -v 6.7.0, webpack etc all fresh installed, seems like it is trying to run a non-transpiled version of webpack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encountered the same issue and was also using node version 0.12.0. Changed to node version 6.9.4, and webpack 1 successfully ran after that.

Comment: Yeah, this is almost definitely a node version issue. v0.12.10 is EOL'd at this point, so OP should upgrade.

Comment: @mAAdhaTTah I had a fairly up to date node version (6.7) and even updated to latest stable and had this issue on both, so no I don't believe this is a node version issue

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me with webpack 2.2.0-rc.3, so "webpack": "2.2.0-rc.3" in your package.json or 'npm install webpack@2.2.0-rc.3'. All other versions are giving me the same or some other issue